# How to change SharePoint quick nav category label using powershell

Tags: 2010, powershell, quick-launch

I have written a powershell script to go through all the sites in a site collection and pulling their quick nav bars. I would like to change the category names in the quick nav, not the links. Here is the code I have written to accomplish this part:

```
$quickLaunchCategory = $quickLaunch | where { $_.Title -eq $category }
$quickLaunchCategory.Title = $newTitle
$quickLaunchCategory.Update()
```

However this doesn't work. PowerShell claims that the property Title cannot be found for `$quickLaunchCategory`. I have also tried getting the members on `$quickLaunchCategory` but then I get the error that `$quickLaunchCategory` is not an object (however I can add links to it if I want to - so I am confused).

The question I have is, how do I change the title of a quick launch category?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried your script and I could successfully update navigation items.

So your problem can be:

1. the "category" that you specified could not be found within navigation items. The result is that `$quickLaunchCategory` is `NULL` when you try to set the Title.
2. you have multiple category with the same name, in that case you get a collection of navigation item

you can do a simple test to check if your category has been found or not and if you get only one or more results:

```
$quickLaunchCategory = $quickLaunch | where { $_.Title -eq $category }
if ($quickLaunchCategory -ne $nul)
{
    if ($quickLaunch.GetType().Name -eq "SPNavigationNodeCollection")
    {
        foreach ($currentNode in $quickLaunchCategory)
        {
            write-host "Multiple categories found for $($category)"
            $currentNode.Title = $newTitle
            $currentNode.Update()
            write-host "$($category) successfully updated to $($newTitle)"
        }
    }
    else
    {
        $quickLaunchCategory.Title = $newTitle
        $quickLaunchCategory.Update()
        write-host "$($category) successfully updated to $($newTitle)"
    }
}
else
{
    write-host "$($category) category could not be found"
}
```

Comment: You are correct in suggesting my problem was having multiple categories matching my search term. Excellent answer and great coding example by the way!